# Private git server restrict Read/Write access by machine

Tags: git, ssh

I'm setting up a private `git server` by following the instructions here - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Now, if the user wants, they can copy their public and private ssh keys from their machine to another machine, which will give them full access (via ssh) to the codebase from another computer. This is what we'd like to avoid. Is there any way to prevent that? I.e. in this case, contributors should only be able to push/pull/clone the repo from their designated computer, and not from their private laptops etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "from=pattern-list" attribute in your authorized_keys file.
This blog describes how to set this up:

https://blog.tinned-software.net/restrict-ssh-logins-using-ssh-keys-to-a-particular-ip-address/

Comment: or use something like iptables